# VPN IP address leak while establishing connection

Tags: vpn, vulnerability

Even if I have a VPN configured to auto-connect in Linux, there is a brief moment where it is connected to the Internet, but not utilizing the VPN. Doesn't this provide a vulnerability? How can I protect myself?

Comment: What vulnerability ? and protect yourself from what exactly ?

Comment: Configure iptables rules that only allow traffic through the VPN tunnel interface.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your vpn software that's normal behaviour.

Configure a firewall that only allows connections to your vpn provider over the public network and force everything else to go over the vpn.

For instance:

```
iptables -P OUTPUT REJECT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d <VPN_SERVER> -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s <VPN_ADDRESS> -d <VPN_NET> -j ACCEPT
```

Where `VPN_SERVER is your VPN provider's public address`, `VPN_ADDRESS` is your address on the tunnel interface and  `VPN_NET` is the VPN network in CIDR notation.

You can also do this with routes instead. When you setup your internet interface, instead of loading a default gateway you load a static route to your vpn server. No host other than your local neighbors and your vpn server will be reachable until you get a default route from the vpn provider (through the vpn).

Both approaches get the job done, but the firewall approach includes an insurance policy for free.